# How to find Machine Name using the UserPrincipal object?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I got the `UserPrincipal` class object and want to find the machine name or ip address or mac address.
Any one of these.
Is it possible to do so, and if yes how?
Apologies if I am asking for any vague thing which is not possible.

Comment: Are you looking for the machine name your code is running on, or the machine name that is linked to a particular UserPrincipal?

Comment: A UserPrincipal represents a *user* - not their machine (unless perhaps it is a machine account)

Comment: Yeah I Know @MarcGravell, but there must be some way to find the machine name using my userPrinicpal object. this object is nothing but a machine connected which is connected in my network domain.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma why "must"? The machine name simply isn't, as far as I can tell, a factor for `UserPrincipal`. Unless the account **is itself** a machine account, in which case, it'll probably be `.Name`

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in the question here; please can you clarify whether you are talking about the name etc of the **current** machine (i.e. where your code is running), versus the machine that some remote user is using.

Comment: @MarcGravell I asked for any of these things such as machine name, Ip or MAC, isn't this achievable as per your knowledge??

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma yes, but you didn't specify ***of which computer*** you are talking. For **which** computer do you want to get the machine-name, the IP, or the MAC? Also: you say "this object is nothing but a machine connected which is connected in my network domain" - to which I say: *no*, this object represents a user; nothing more. A user is not their machine, nor is it "a user in the context of a machine". It is just: a user.

Comment: @marcGravell Yes, its just a user, but I want the name of the machine to which this user is logged on.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma that is not, AFAIK, a feature of `UserPrincipal`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36651/discussion-between-prakash-vishwakarma-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 3):

A UserPrincipal object only identifies a user, not a machine (unless your network administrators have decided to identify PC's as users).

So there really is no standard answer to your question. If there is a user -> pc link, it's probably stored in Active Directory or a database somewhere. Contact your system administrator(s) to find out how to make that link.

Answer (score 0):

To find the host computer's name, use

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

If you are looking for the host's IP address, use this:

```
var address = System.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName)
     .AddressList
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

This gives you the first address of type "`InterNetwork`" -- i.e., the first known IP address. Of course there may be multiple IP addresses linked to the host, in that case you should iterate the `AddressList` property seen above.

Comment: I think the OP means the remote user's machine name

Comment: I see no reference to a remote user anywhere in the question...

Comment: @RoyDictus Maybe in comments?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string sysname = Environment.MachineName;
string sysname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string sysname = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;
string sysname = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME');
```

May be this is what you mean:

Too from [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Computer-names-on-network-c)

```
ArrayList nets = new ArrayList();

DirectoryEntry entryPC;
entryPC = new DirectoryEntry();
entryPC.Path = "WinNT://domainName";

foreach (DirectoryEntry child in entryPC.Children)
{
   if (child.Name != "Schema")
   nets.Add(child.Name);
  }

return nets;
```

Comment: That's username.. not computer name.

Comment: I want machine name of my UserPrincipal object which is in my network domain.

Comment: UserPrincipal object is not of my local machine which I am working upon, its a machine connected to a network. So above answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: may be this is what you're looking for http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Computer-names-on-network-c